How to transpose a table after import it in an org file automatically?
I read a table from a txt file as follows and how do I transpose it by script? It seems that org-table-transpose-table-at-point function could not be used in the script. Are there any built-in functions to shorten the script?
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (org-table-import "ttt.out" nil)
#+end_src

The file ttt.out will be:
#Cluster   Frames   Rep RepScore   Rep RepScore
       0      23      2      0.6     6      0.4 
       1      10      5      0.1     3      0.5
       2       5      4      0.4     5      0.6
       3       4      1      0.4     2      0.6

The results I need (transpose).
| #Cluster |   0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |
| Frames   |  23 |  10 |   5 |   4 |
| Rep      |   2 |   5 |   4 |   1 |
| RepScore | 0.6 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 0.4 |
| Rep      |   6 |   3 |   5 |   2 |
| RepScore | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.6 |

Extra
The transpose could use org-babel from (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-04/msg00239.html)
However, it did not work as follows:
(apply #'mapcar* #'list (org-table-import "ttt.out" nil))

What happened?

You seem to have asked multiple questions using the phrase "How to write a LISP to...?".  LISP / Lisp is a family of programming languages.  One doesn't "write a lisp" unless creating a new language, which none of your questions are about.  You should edit your questions so that they make better sense.

In the link you provide the table is passed in to babel block as a variable. (org-table-import "ttt.out" nil) doesn't return anything so the apply has nothing to work on.
Here is one solution for you:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results org
(with-temp-buffer "tmp.org"
          (org-table-import "ttt.out" nil)
          (org-table-transpose-table-at-point)
          (buffer-string))
#+END_SRC

That returns the table as as string, and you could insert it where you want.
(assuming you want emacs-lisp here)

Thank you. It works. However, I turn to use R tidyverse to manipulate the table for I need do some delete/add rows/columns and many other manipulations. The tidyverse are more flexible than org table. Certainly, I return the data frame to org to visulize it.
